# Last command starting with

Tags: bash, terminal, ubuntu-8.04

Using BASH, you can get the last command (when connected through a PuTty terminal) using the UP arrow key.

I want to know if there's a way to "autocomplete" the last command I did **starting with** mail, for example.

In Google Chrome, for instance, the way the address bar works, by narrowing down from your previous web history the site you are trying to visit.

So what I want to do is start to type "mail", then press the UP key for example, and the **last command starting with mail** gets autocompleted.  If I press up again, then the 2nd last command starting with mail get autocompleted.

Is this possible in BASH?

Answer (score 7):

Hit **CTRL + R** it will start the reverse history search. If you want a second command with the string you wish to find, continue hitting **CTRL + R** until you find the command with what you want.

You can also use the **history** command to see the last commands you have entered.

Answer (score 4):

You can bind the `readline` function `history-search-backward` to a keystroke (and `history-search-forward` to another). I have them bound to <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> which on my system are `^[[5~` and `^[[6~` so I have the following in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Using that, you type the beginning of the line you want, `mail` for example, then press <kbd>PgUp</kbd> repeatedly until you get the previous line that you're looking for. You can press <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to step back forward through the list. The difference with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is that with it you press the key first then it matches any string *anywhere within* the line rather than only at the beginning. I find that I use both methods depending on what I'm doing.

You can step back forward after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> a few times by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> if you have `forward-search-history` bound to it and you have `stty -ixon` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Note the subtle difference between `history-search-forward` and `forward-search-history`.

Comment: How did you do the key things? For the buttons.

Comment: @freedom: `<kbd>Key</kbd>`

Answer (score 1):

One way to execute the last command beginning with mail is `!mail` but it won't let you scroll up, it's last or nothing (method above is better :))

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the last command with !!